# Type argument not recognized in Kotlin

Tags: android, gson, kotlin

Using gson and retrofit and created a JsonDeserializer.

In java, the class is defined as:

```
public class Test implements JsonDeserializer<NavigationMenu[]> {...
```

In Kotlin, it is defined as:

```
class NavigationMenuArrayDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Array<NavigationMenu>> {...
```

The java class is called as expected after being registered with GSON.  The Kotlin class is never called.

```
Retrofit jsonClient = new Retrofit
                .Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(getGsonConverter())
                .build();
```

...

```
private GsonConverterFactory getGsonConverter() {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.setLenient();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(NavigationMenu[].class, new NavigationMenuArrayDeserializer());
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    return GsonConverterFactory.create(gson);
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Have you registered it, like the `JavaDoc` shows it: https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html

Comment: Can you show us the code in which you are using this deserializer?

Comment: I'm hesitant because the company I work for may have issues with that.  I will tell you that the class never gets called, so none of the code runs.  When I switched the kotlin to java, it ran fine.  It's something in the kotlin Array<Object> vs the java Object[] but I can't say what for sure

Comment: Maybe it needs to be `Array<NavigationMenu>! `?

Comment: Apparently that is not valid syntax according to the language. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: How is the class even called?

Comment: @creativecreatorormabyenot I've added that info to the OP

Comment: @Psest328 the code you provided works perfectly fine for both cases. take a look at this simple repo https://github.com/varren/KotlinAndJava (without android part) what are you doing differently?

Comment: @Psest328 yo, has it been solved by any of the answers?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I've been away since Tuesday and will be back this coming Tuesday. Will test all suggestions then :)

Comment: I guess that is just in time for handing out bounty if successful :D

Comment: @EpicPandaForce unfortunately, neither suggestion worked.  Calling the kotlin class type from java still not working.  I'm going to switch the singleton to kotlin as I know calling java class types from kotlin has no issue.  Going to close this at end of day

Comment: @Psest328 Please post an answer so that I can put the bounty on it I have 3 hours to do that thank you

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I don't feel right collecting a bounty on my own question... you sure about doing that?

Comment: @Psest328 Better than giving a bounty to answers that don't work!

Comment: @EpicPandaForce it's up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no suggestion worked for me.  I converted the calling class from java to kotlin as calling java class types in kotlin has easily worked for me in the past... and that did the trick.

My original attempt at calling kotlin array class from a java class is still unsuccessful but I was able to get the configuration working so I'm calling this complete.

Converting the configuration java code in the OP to Kotlin did the trick:

```
private val gsonConverter: GsonConverterFactory
    get() {
        val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder()
        gsonBuilder.setLenient()
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Array<NavigationMenu>::class.java, NavigationMenuArrayDeserializer())
        val gson = gsonBuilder.create()
        return GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)
    }
```

Comment: just posted the code.  no magic, just doing the "convert to kotlin" fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue using the array class. Try something like this:

```
val clazz = (Array<NavigationMenu>::class).java
gson.fromJson(json, clazz)
```

I hope this might help.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `TypeToken` like this.

```
private GsonConverterFactory getGsonConverter() {

     val type = object : TypeToken< ArrayList < NavigationMenu >>(){}.getType()

     GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
     gsonBuilder.setLenient();

     gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(type, new NavigationMenuArrayDeserializer());

     Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
     return GsonConverterFactory.create(gson);
}
```